# Precedence of elementwise multiplication in Matlab

Tags: matlab, operator-precedence

**Matlab**

```
ones(2,2)*2.*ones(2,2)

ans =

     2     2
     2     2

ones(2,2).*2*ones(2,2)

ans =

     4     4
     4     4
```

Comment: I would suggest you to perform the operation by hand (from left to right) and taking into account the difference between `*` (normal matrix product) and `.*` (elementwise matrix product). The [Getting Started](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) tutorial may be useful to you.

Comment: Also take a look at the documented [Operator Precedence](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/operator-precedence.html).

Comment: @rayryeng : Thank you very much for the nice answer Ray.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.*` and `*` are the same precedence, so you are reading the expressions from left to right.

The first one creates a `2 x 2` matrix of all ones, scales the elements by 2 then element-wise multiplies (i.e. `.*`) the matrix by another matrix of all ones of the same size, thus giving a result of all 2s.  Note that performing `2 * ones(2, 2)` and `2 .* ones(2, 2)` gives exactly the same result of creating a matrix of size `2 x 2` of all 2s.  It's some nice syntactic sugar that MATLAB has.  Also note that reversing the order of the operands gives the same results, so `ones(2, 2) * 2` and `ones(2, 2) .* 2` gives the same result.

The second one creates a `2 x 2` matrix of all ones, scales the elements by 2 then **matrix-multiplies** (i.e. `*`) the matrix with another matrix of all ones, thus giving you a result of all 4s.

Element-wise multiplication and matrix multiplication are two completely different things.  The former ensures that both matrices are the same size, with the exception that either one of the operands is a scalar, and creates a matrix of the same size as either operand with each element in the output being multiplied by the corresponding positions between both matrices.  Concretely, given that `C(i, j)` is the output matrix `C` at location `(i, j)`, `C(i, j) = A(i, j) * B(i, j)`.  Matrix multiplication is the multiplication of two matrices using the laws of linear algebra.  I won't insult your intelligence and explain what those are as your profile alludes to you being a mathematician.

It's no mystery.  If you want to convince yourself, enter each part of the expression reading from the left to the right, chaining the previous results together and you'll see that it's correct:

```
>> A = ones(2, 2)

A =

          1.00          1.00
          1.00          1.00

>> A = A * 2

A =

          2.00          2.00
          2.00          2.00

>> A = A .* ones(2, 2)

A =

          2.00          2.00
          2.00          2.00

>> B = ones(2, 2)

B =

          1.00          1.00
          1.00          1.00

>> B = B .* 2

B =

          2.00          2.00
          2.00          2.00

>> B = B * ones(2, 2)

B =

          4.00          4.00
          4.00          4.00
```

I also encourage reading the documentation on the differences between the two: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/times.html, https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mtimes.html.